# Can I pick up environment variables in vbscript WSH script?

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables, wsh

Is is possible to read system environment variables in a Windows Scripting Host (WSH) VBS script?

(I am writing a VBScript using Windows Scripting Host for task for a Cruise Control and want to pick up the project build URL.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's an example (taken from [here](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/84803/jsi-tip-9956-how-do-i-use-an-environment-variable-in-vbscript.html)):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
user=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")
comp=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ComputerName%")
WScript.Echo user & " " & comp
```

Answer (score 10):

The existing answers are all helpful, but let me attempt a **pragmatic summary**:

Typically, you want **the *current process's* definition of an environment variable**:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
```

This is the equivalent of (note the absence of `%` around the variable name):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process").Item("TEMP")
```

<sup>**Caveat**: Do not omit the `("Process)` part: if you do, you'll get the *system* scope's definition of the variable; see below.</sup>

**`.ExpandEnvironmentStrings` is conceptually simpler and more flexible**: It can expand *arbitrary* strings with *embedded* (`%`-enclosed) environment-variable references; e.g.:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("My name is %USERNAME%")
```

---

On rare occasions you may have to **access environment-variable definitions from a *specific scope*** (other than the current process's).

```
  sScope = "System" ' May be: "Process", "User", "Volatile", "System"
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment(sScope).Item("TEMP")
```

Note: As stated above, omitting the scope argument defaults to the `System` scope.

**Caveat**: Accessing a value this way does not *expand* it: Environment-variable values can be *nested*: they can refer to *other* environment variables.
In the example above, the return value is `%SystemRoot%\TEMP`, which contains the *unexpanded* reference to `%SystemRoot%`.
To expand the result, pass it to `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`, as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 7):

From [here](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/vbscript-systems-administrator/using-environment-variables-inside-a-vbscript-script/) ...

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set WshProccessEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("System")

Wscript.Echo WshSysEnv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")
Wscript.Echo WshProccessEnv("Path")
```

Also, much more [detail on TechNet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_wsh_kmmj.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 6):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment
WScript.Echo "WINDIR=" & WshEnv.Item("WINDIR")  & vbCrLf & vbCrLf   
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo "Environment System:"              & vbCrLf & _ 
         "..............................................."

For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("System")
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Environment User:"       & vbCrLf & _   
        "..............................................."

For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("User") 
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Environment Volatile:"   & vbCrLf & _ 
       "..............................................."

For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("Volatile")
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Environment Process:"    & vbCrLf & _ 
       "..............................................."

For Each IEnv In WshShell.Environment("Process")
    WScript.Echo IEnv
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
Dim objNetwork
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
MsgBox objNetwork.UserName
```

or from the shell:

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
```

or from environment variable (it should work, but when i tested it was wrong!):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment
MsgBox "USERNAME=" & WshEnv.Item("USERNAME")
```

Comment: The [object returned by `CreateObject("WScript.Network"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6wt333f(v=vs.84).aspx) does not provide generic environment-variable access, it just happens to expose 3 values as properties that are also reflected in environment variables: `ComputerName`, `UserDomain`, and `UserName`. The reason that your last example doesn't work is that `WshShell.Environment` is the same as `WshShell.Environment("System")`, and `%USERNAME%` isn't defined in the _system_ scope.