# Create a text file in %temp% and write content in it using vbs

Tags: vbscript, ms-office, special-folders

Basically, I want to create a new file and write in it in a directory on the PC, pointed to by the `%TEMP%` variable. However, the revised code below does not work:

```
Dim oFile
Dim shell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
user = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Set oFile = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oFile = oFile.CreateTextFile("%Temp%\d.txt")
oFile.WriteLine "here is my contant"
oFile.Close
```

Error Message:

> run time error
>   line no: 3
>   object required

## Old Code

```
Dim fso, tf
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileName = "%TEMP%\myfile.txt"
Set tf = fso.CreateTextFile(FileName, True)
```

If I use the file name "C:\myfile.txt" it works fine.

Error Message:

> Path not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pick up environment variables in vbscript WSH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904739/can-i-pick-up-environment-variables-in-vbscript-wsh-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, you can just use `Environ("TEMP")` to expand the Environment variable - if this does not work in VBScript, you may need to bind the `WScript.Shell` object and use the `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` property instead, like so:

```vb
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
FileName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") & "\myfile.txt"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

## Following from comments below

Here is a "fully fixed" code:

```vb
'Declare variables/objects first
Dim fso AS Object, oFile AS Object
Dim oShell AS Object, FileName AS String

'This bit turns "%TEMP%" into a real file path
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
FileName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%\d.txt")
Set oShell = Nothing 'Tidy up the Objects we no longer need

'This bit creates the file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FileName)
oFile.WriteLine "here is my content"
oFile.Close
Set oFile = Nothing 'Tidy up the Objects we no longer need
Set fso = Nothing 'Tidy up the Objects we no longer need
```

Comment: `oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%\myfile.txt")`

Comment: sir not working :Dim oShell,tf
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
FileName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")& "\myfile.txt"
Set tf = oShell.CreateTextFile(FileName, True)

Comment: @minikumari "Doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. How *exactly* does your modified attempt "not work"? Does it still give you an error? A different one? Please edit your question.

Comment: @minikumari If you use a `MsgBox` to display `FileName` after you set it, does it display a valid path (navigate there manually?)  Also, do you actually have permissions to view/edit the folder, or is it restricted?

Comment: `Dim oFile
Dim shell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
user = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Set oFile = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oFile = oFile.CreateTextFile("%Temp%\d.txt")
oFile.WriteLine "here is my contant"
oFile.Close`
   **error in line no: 3 object required.**

Comment: @minikumari You have `Dim shell` instead of `Dim oShell As Object` - the object names don't match, and leaving all of your Variable/Object types defaulting to `Variant` is *very* sloppy coding...  (Also, a good practice in 1-line-VisualBasic is to use `:` for a new-line, as VB will actually *read* it as a new-line - the opposite of `_` as "continued on next line")

Comment: @ Chronocidal Error Message:

Run-time error "438"
Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @minikumari That's because you're creating 2 `WScript.Shell` objects, instead of making the second one `Scripting.FileSystemObject`.  Try this: `Dim fso AS Object, oFile AS Object:Dim oShell AS Object, FileName AS String:Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"):FileName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%\d.txt"):Set oShell = Nothing:Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"):Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FileName):oFile.WriteLine "here is my content":oFile.Close:Set oFile = Nothing:Set fso = Nothing`

Comment: If this is VBScript then this doesn't work, so something is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Environ("temp")` to write to `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp`